# How to add loop in my code

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsarray, nsdate

I have `NSMutableArray *arrList` and I founded *Monday* objects in `MutableArray *arrList`. But now is static written in if condition, Look like in my code:(`if ([str containsString:@"Monday"])`).  I want a array load place to static *Monday*. That mean loop wise one by one week day load in static Monday.

```
NSArray*loopAry = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",nil];
```

That is `loopAry` objects one by one reload to place Static *Monday*.

This helps to get dynamic code and reload only array in loop and get weekdays data

```
NSMutableArray *arrList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"25-11-2016, Friday",
   @"26-11-2016, Saturday",
   @"27-11-2016, Sunday",
   @"28-11-2016, Monday",
   @"29-11-2016, Tuesday",
   @"30-11-2016, Wednesday",
   @"01-12-2016, Thursday",
   @"02-12-2016, Friday",
   @"03-12-2016, Saturday",
   @"04-12-2016, Sunday",
   @"05-12-2016, Monday",
   @"06-12-2016, Tuesday",
   @"07-12-2016, Wednesday", nil];

NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (id element in  arrList){
NSString *str = element;
    if ([str containsString:@"Monday"]) {
        [result addObject:element];
    }
}

// print result
NSLog(@"%@",result);
 (
"28-11-2016, Monday",
"05-12-2016, Monday"
)
```

Comment: you want only place Static Monday.

Comment: I am not clear with your question. Can you please tell us what you want here ?

Comment: @NarendraPandey No i want a loop and static Monday place to one bye one array(loopAry) objects load and add in result array list.

Comment: Ok so you want array containing only Monday

Comment: @CodeChanger I want a add loop in my code. IN my code if condition written in Monday that place to want one by one array objects reload and add in result array list

Comment: @NarendraPandey I want NSArray*loopAry = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",nil]; in array objects load one bye one

Comment: @NarendraPandey This time find only Monday objects But i want every objects find in this loopAry

Comment: I am not getting your point. First thing Be clear what you are asking. Here only thing i got You want ONLY MONDAY in your array. after then sequence of WEEK. what you want actually :)

Comment: if ([str containsString:@"Monday"]) {
        [result addObject:element];
    } This will only find Monday.  remove this IF you will get all data

Comment: Check my answer hope this will help you to get your weekday result.

Comment: @NarendraPandey That time get only Monday. but i want loopAry objects through get weekdays suppose NSArray*loopAry = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",nil];  In this object `Sunday`, `Monday`, `Tuesday`   and how to one by one in that place to change `if ([str containsString:@"Sunday"])`, `if ([str containsString:@"Monday"])`, `if ([str containsString:@"Tuesday"])`

Comment: Why not just us a dictionary with the day names as key and a mutable array as value in which you enter the objects form the list? (Given that I understood the question and the comments, as I find it incomprehensible.)

Comment: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday if you want only three then check answer of @CodeChanger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Array of provided day like below :

```
NSArray *loopAry = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",nil];

NSMutableArray *arrList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"25-11-2016, Friday",
                               @"26-11-2016, Saturday",
                               @"27-11-2016, Sunday",
                               @"28-11-2016, Monday",
                               @"29-11-2016, Tuesday",
                               @"30-11-2016, Wednesday",
                               @"01-12-2016, Thursday",
                               @"02-12-2016, Friday",
                               @"03-12-2016, Saturday",
                               @"04-12-2016, Sunday",
                               @"05-12-2016, Monday",
                               @"06-12-2016, Tuesday",
                               @"07-12-2016, Wednesday", nil];

NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSString *strData in  arrList){
    //2nd Loop for your weekdays array.By this you will get weekdays array in result.
    for (NSString *strDay in loopAry) {
        if ([strData containsString:strDay]) {
              [result addObject:strData];
        }
    }

}

// print result
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Hope this will help you to get week days.

Comment: Thank for give your precious time.  Thankyou so much solve my problem :)